# printing the key and the values when a key has been searched and found in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, key

my text file:

45623189 Intel Core i7, 337.71, 10, 5,

63217452 Intel Core i5, 239.58, 10, 5,

14527869 Intel Core i3, 120.89, 10, 5,

85274198 Gigabyte GeForce GTX, 244.86, 10, 5,

32145687 Sapphire AMD Radeon RX, 254.40, 10 5,

98754236 MSI Radeon RX, 265.45, 10, 5,

63874129 ASUS GeForce GTX, 429.00, 10, 5,

My Code:

```
gtin8 = input("Enter GTIN8 code to serach for: ")

for key, value in d.items():
    if gtin8 in d:
        print(key[gtin8], "=", value)

else:
    print("Product not found")
```

the output i get:

> Enter GTIN8 code to serach for: 98754236
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "GTIN-8.py", line 60, in 
>       print(key[gtin8], "=", value)
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers

I am trying to find the code in the file and return the key and all its values once found but seem to be stuck at this point. I have tried converting gtin8 variable to an int but still get an error.

Any ideas?

Darth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you take the input the default type is string. so typecast it in integer.

```
gtin8 = int(gtin8)
```

EDITED:
for your problem just use :

```
gtin8 = input("Enter GTIN8 code to serach for: ")
if gtin8 in d:
    print "key = ", gtin8,"value = ", d[gtin8]
else:
    print("Product not found")
```

Comment: I tried that before but it kept saying product not found when it does exist so i changed it back to normal.

Comment: I edited the answer. If you get anything wrong then let me know

Comment: i would prefer the key and value to be read like:    14527869': ['Intel', 'Core', 'i3,', '120.89,', '10,', '5,'] as i need to update elements of this key and update the textfile accordingly.

Comment: ok im going to try pulling some of the values from this key to see if i can change them and then send the changed values back to the text file to update the appropriate key

Comment: as your value is a list you can access individual elements of the list as dic[key][0] is first element, dic[key][1] being second and so on.

Comment: when i multiply say item 4 in the value by 3, instead of giving me 30 it gives me 10, 10, 10. How can i convert item 4 to an int?

Comment: try this : dic[key][3]=int(dic[key][3])*3

Comment: it still does the same:     Enter GTIN8 code to serach for: 98754236
key =  98754236  value =  ['MSI', 'Radeon', 'RX,', '265.45,', '10,', '5,']
key =  98754236  value =  ['MSI', 'Radeon', 'RX,', '265.45,', '10,', '5,']
the price of item 98754236 is: £ 10,
265.45,265.45,265.45,